# Anti Forgery Token Axios Asp .Net Core

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, axios, asp.net-core-2.2

Hi i am able to send a post using vue js axios to a controller in Asp .NET Core 2.2 like this

```
                axios({
                    url: '/Parametros/Create',
                    method: 'post',                    
                    ContentType: 'application/json',
                    data: formData                        
                })
```

however for this to work i have to remove from my action in controller

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
```

Also the token is generated in razor pages as input

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8GwWLSmGzLVOqfs-yISjocyQshOjT98BeCqxo14sO91JGUZPe_IstyK9DWZyu0rCr0bxdx3lBlwminvxm7q0zXVWcUkAZIH8NwKDYGdNCiY-Z_BgMzLt_1PyNEHxfpmTouJgMu3il8N4fMjbI0ohwElXGK-eVLXGuzj_J5N_uQ3A4f-9ijmTKGk8p3BC7hrB1A">
```

I tried

```
axios({
    url: '/Parametros/Create',
    method: 'post',
    headers: { 
        "__RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
    }                    
    ContentType: 'application/json',
    data: formData                        
})
```

and

```
axios({
    url: '/Parametros/Create',
    method: 'post',                  
    ContentType: 'application/json',
    data: {
        "__RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val(),
        formData                        
    }
})
```

None work, I keep getting bad request... Using ajax the 2nd approach works fine but axios not. How can i handle this?

Comment: Include __RequestVerificationToken and it's value in your formData

Comment: you mean as a property of the object?

Comment: Yes, just like any other input data you're sending to the controller

Comment: formData.__RequestVerificationToken = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val(),  ........ I did this and still gives me bad request in both approaches

Answer (score 8):

Changing `__RequestVerificationToken` to `RequestVerificationToken` in the header made a post request work for me.

Final code:

```
         axios({
            method: 'post',
            headers: {  "RequestVerificationToken":   $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()},
            url:  'home/axiostest',
          })
...
```